# Why is React not re-rendering on setState?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have a React project for a todo list. When you click to delete a task, it successfully sends the request to the API and removes the task from the database. After that, I request the tasks again and then setState with the new task list. After using setState, nothing updates on the website until you refresh the page.

What am I doing wrong? I'm brand new to React so any explanation, I would be very grateful for!

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import taskApi from "../api/task-api";
import TaskList from "./TaskList";
import {Button, Container} from "react-bootstrap";

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        tasks: [],
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        taskApi.get('/tasks').then(
            res => {
                const tasks = res.data.data;
                this.setState({tasks})
            }
        );

    }


    render() {
        return(
            <Container>
                <h1>Task Manager</h1>
                <Button variant="primary" size="lg" className="add-task-button">Add Task</Button>
                <TaskList tasks={this.state.tasks} />
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**TaskList.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table'

import TaskItem from "./TaskItem";

class TaskList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
                <Table striped bordered hover>
                    <thead>
                        <tr key="header">
                            <th>ID #</th>
                            <th>Task Name</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {this.props.tasks.map((task) => {
                        return <TaskItem task={task} key={task.id} />
                    })}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
        );
    }
}

export default TaskList;
```

**TaskItem.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button, Modal} from "react-bootstrap";
import taskApi from "../api/task-api";


class TaskItem extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            show: false,
        };
    }

    showModal() {
        this.setState({show: true});
    }

    closeModal() {
        this.setState({show: false});
    }

    deleteTask(task_id) {
        this.setState({show: false});
        taskApi.delete('/task/' + task_id).then(()=>{
            taskApi.get('/tasks').then(
                res => {
                    const tasks = res.data.data;
                    this.setState({tasks})
                }
            );
            }
        );
    }

    render() {
        return(
                <tr>
                    <td>{this.props.task.id}</td>
                    <td>{this.props.task.task_name}</td>
                    <td>
                        <Button variant="success" className="task-action-button">Complete</Button>
                        <Button variant="secondary" className="task-action-button">Edit</Button>
                        <Button variant="danger" className="task-action-button" onClick={()=>{this.showModal()}}>Delete</Button>
                        <Modal show={this.state.show}>
                            <Modal.Header>Confirm</Modal.Header>
                            <Modal.Body>
                                Are you sure you want to delete this task?
                                <br/><br/>
                                <strong>Task:</strong>
                                <br/>
                                {this.props.task.task_name}
                            </Modal.Body>
                            <Modal.Footer>
                                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={()=>{this.closeModal()}}>Cancel</Button>
                                <Button variant="danger" onClick={()=>{this.deleteTask(this.props.task.id)}}>Delete</Button>
                            </Modal.Footer>
                        </Modal>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        );
    }
}

export default TaskItem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're doing

```
class TaskItem extends React.Component {
    deleteTask(task_id) {
        // ...
        this.setState({tasks})
```

You're setting state in `TaskItem` - but you never reference `this.state.tasks` in TaskItem. The tasks state exists in the parent, inside your `class App`. So, updating the state in the child component doesn't do anything - you need to update the state in the parent instead.

Put the methods that need to manipulate the parent's state in the parent, and then pass them down.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    deleteTask = (task_id) => {
        taskApi.delete('/task/' + task_id).then(()=>{
             // ...
```

App's render method:

```
<TaskList tasks={this.state.tasks} deleteTask={this.deleteTask} />
```

TaskList's render method:

```
return <TaskItem task={task} key={task.id} deleteTask={this.props.deleteTask} />
```

And finally in TaskItem:

```
deleteTask(task_id) {
    this.setState({show: false});
    this.props.deleteTask(task_id);
}
```

Comment: Hello @CertainPerformance, thank you so much for the explanation. This really made a lot of sense, and I was able to fix my code. Thank you again!